# ReadAllTextFile vs. StreamReader for JSON Parsing

Tags: c#, json, io, json.net

This is more of a theoretical question, but I am curious what the difference between these two methods of reading a file is and why I would want to choose one over the other.

I am parsing a JSON configuration file (from local disk). Here is one method of doing it:

```
// Uses JSON.NET Serializer + StreamReader
using(var s = new StreamReader(file))
{
  var jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr);
  var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
  return jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Configuration>(jtr);
}
```

...and, the second option...

```
// Reads the entire file and deserializes.
var json = File.ReadAllText(file);
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonVmrConfigurationProvider>(json);
```

Is one any better than the other? Is there a case where one or the other should be used?

Again, this is more theoretical, but, I realized I don't really know the answer to it, and a search online didn't produce results that satisfied me. I could see the second being bad if the file was large (it isn't) since it's being read into memory in one shot. Any other reasons?

Comment: I can see that the first *might* stream the text into the deserializer rather that load all the text in one go beforehand. This would have preferable memory characteristics in the case that the JSON is very large. It all depends on Json.net's implementation.

Comment: may be the second prevents you from forgetting disposing the JsonTextReader ? :)

Comment: @tschmit007 : Seeing as there's probably only a single disposable resource (the open file), the second dispose would probably be redundant. For similar BCL constructs, double usings fire CA2202 warning for exactly this reason. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx It's kindof confusing though... I was surprised to see CA2202 pop up. See this question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx

Comment: well, reading the Close method from [JsonReader Source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonReader.cs), it seems that the reader does not care about the stream. But from the same source, I would say **probably** no leak (depending on the _value effective type in fact). Thanks for the CA2202 anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by reading the code you found that deserializaton from a string finally reach:

```
public static object DeserializeObject(string value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull(value, "value");

        JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);

        // by default DeserializeObject should check for additional content
        if (!jsonSerializer.IsCheckAdditionalContentSet())
            jsonSerializer.CheckAdditionalContent = true;

        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(value)))
        {
            return jsonSerializer.Deserialize(reader, type);
        }
    }
```

That is the creation of a JsonTextReader.

So the difference seems to effectively be the handling of huge files.

-- previous comment temper:

JsonTextReader overrides JsonReader.Close() and handles the stream (if CloseInput is true), but not only.

CloseInput should be true by default as the StringReader is not explicitly disposed in previous fragment of code

Answer (score 1):

With `File.ReadAllText()`, the entire JSON needs to be loaded into memory first before deserializing it.  Using a `StreamReader`, the file is read and deserialized incrementally.  So if your file is huge, you might want to use the `StreamReader` to avoid loading the whole file into memory.  If your JSON file is small (most cases), it doesn't really make a difference.